# Получать директорию повторно или передавать через Navigator, как параметр?

Tags: flutter, dart

В одном классе (одна страница) я получаю директорию, используя **final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();**
В этом классе я читаю файл.

Во втором классе (другая страница) я буду сохранять файл. Как правильней поступать в таких случаях - в этом классе также применять **final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();** или же передавать через *Navigator* параметр *path* из одного класса в другой? И там уже *path* допилять до вида, в каком она есть после **getExternalStorageDirectory()**.

Comment: Сложно сказать какой подход "правильный". Могу только посоветовать использовать тот, который Вам удобнее. Потому-что если разбираться, то кто-то другой Вам может сказать, что оба подхода могут быть потенциально неправильными, а правильным будет выносить всю бизнес-логику из UI в отдельные слой, всю работу с хранилищами выносить из бизнес-логики в репозитории, и т.д. Вы к этому всему придёте со временем, но сейчас нет принципиальной разницы, как Вы передадите этот путь до каталога.

Comment: Спасибо. По вашему совету вынес в отдельный файл. Код стал приятнее читаться. Убрались вызовы/возвраты.
В общем... маленькими шажками.